# Fluent NHibernate multiple abstract class inheritance. How create table per concrete class without create table in db for abstract class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have base abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public User LastChangedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastChangedDate { get; set; }

    public bool Removed { get; set; }

    public string Uid { get; }
}
```

And i have another abstract class:

```
public abstract class Document : BaseEntity, IDocument
{
    public Document()
    {
    }

    public int? Number { get; set; }

    public int? AdditionalNum { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

From this Document class inherited two normal clases:

```
public class Incoming : Document
{
}
public class Outgoing : Document
{
}
```

Classes mapped in fluent like this:

```
public class BaseEntityMap : ClassMap<BaseEntity>
{
    public BaseEntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(x => x.CreatedDate);
        Map(x => x.LastChangedDate);
        Map(x => x.Removed);
        Map(x => x.Uid);

        References(x => x.CreatedBy).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References(x => x.LastChangedBy).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
    }
}

public class DocumentMap : SubclassMap<Document>
{
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Number);
        Map(x => x.AdditionalNum);
        Map(x => x.Header);
        Map(x => x.Summary);
        Map(x => x.FullNumber);
        Map(x => x.Archive);
        Map(x => x.CaseDate);
        Map(x => x.CloseMark);

        References(x => x.NewFirstPage).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References(x => x.NewSealPage).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References(x => x.Type).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References(x => x.Stage).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References(x => x.Case).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        HasMany(x => x.Attaches).Inverse();
    }
}

public class IncomingMap : SubclassMap<Incoming>
{
    public IncomingMap()
    {
        Extends(typeof(Document));
        Table("tbl_Incoming");

        Map(x => x.Resolution);
        Map(x => x.ResolutionDate);
        Map(x => x.OrganizationOutgoingNumber);
        Map(x => x.OrganizationOutgoingDate);
        Map(x => x.IncomingDocumentType);

        References(x => x.From).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        References(x => x.ResolutionEmployee).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}

public class OutgoingMap : SubclassMap<Outgoing>
{
    public OutgoingMap()
    {
        Extends(typeof(Document));
        Table("tbl_Outgoing");

        Map(x => x.DivisionNumber);
        Map(x => x.OrganizationIncomingNumber);
        Map(x => x.OrganizationIncomingDate);
        Map(x => x.OrganizationResolution);
        Map(x => x.Reserved);
        Map(x => x.AgreementNeed);
        Map(x => x.AgreementStatus);

        References(x => x.Author).Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        HasMany(x => x.OutgoingAdresses).Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.SignedEmployees).Inverse();
    }
}
```

This scenario now generate Document table in DB. How map incoming and outgoing table with all properties prom abstract `BaseEntity` And `Document` without create `Document` table in database.

Comment: I could be wrong, but if you just map `Incoming` and `Outgoing` with a regular `ClassMap<T>`, I think you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BaseEntityMap`, you use `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping`. I am not used to Fluent, but it seems that under the hood it does two things:

- Convert all subclasses mapping of the entity to `union-subclass` ([table per concrete type strategy](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete)).
- Flag the base entity as abstract (thus no table for it).

What is missing in your `DocumentMap` is telling to NHibernate that `Document` is abstract too. I guess Fluent has something like an `Abstract()` call for allowing specifying that. At least that is what we can do on `union-subclass` with hbm mapping.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I just add `Abstract();` for all subclasses in my mapping code, and now my scheme is what i need.